# SSRS 2015 Report Pagination Issues

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, reporting-services, visual-studio-2015

I'm building a series of SSRS reports in Visual Studio 2015 such that the first report is a summary, which then feeds into a detail report through a link and a couple parameters.

My problem is that when I click through to the second report, no matter how many rows are present in the report (and in some cases it can be upwards of 20,000 records), they all show on one page, making the report run super-slow, or just hang completely.

I want to break up the detail report into several pages so it will load faster, instead of all records displaying on one page.

I've tried setting the interactive height and the page height through the report properties window with no luck.

How can I force the detail report to break up into pages so it doesn't display all the records on one page?

Comment: Do you have the *Keep together on one page if possible* property set to true for the detail table? If so, turn that off. You can find that in the Tablix Properties, or the properties pane (KeepTogether)

Comment: Yes, I have tried that as well, and to no avail sadly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the problem: My report had a page-level field I set up when I initially created the report by dragging the field into the "Page" section of the wizard, and, for some reason, this was forcing the tablix to keep to one page regardless of size. I pulled out the page-level field and simply added a text box with the field in it instead and the page split every 8 inches like I set it to do.